# Get Professors in Each Departments :: Comment Count SQL

Tags: sql

So, I tried using this query:

```
SELECT name, pID, fname, lname, picpath, email
FROM Department, Professor
WHERE Department.dID = Professor.dID
AND Department.dID = ?
AND Professor_Comment.pcID = Professor.pcID
AND Professor_Comment.pcID = Comment.pcID;
```

This did not work. It returns 0 results

My tables look like:
Department - [image: dept]

Professor - [image: prof]

Professor Comment - [image: prof_comm]

Comment - [image: comment]

Comment: where is your join to `Professor_Comment`?

Comment: It should give you an error. You reference `Professor_Comment` in the `WHERE` but not the `FROM`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are learning I would suggest constructing this a piece at a time to better understand what is happening so that you can solve this.

For example, first, construct the query to return the Department name and Professor information first.  Something like:

```
SELECT name, pID, fname, lname, picpath, email 
FROM Department, Professor 
WHERE Department.dID = Professor.dID AND Department.dID = ?
```

I would suggest using aliases to make it easier to follow.  Not sure if you have been taught this yet but it does make reading the query much easier:

```
SELECT d.name, p.pID, p.fname, p.lname, p.picpath, p.email 
FROM Department d, Professor p
WHERE d.dID = p.dID AND d.dID = ?
```

Then add in the next table to join and so on until it returns everything you need.

Also the join you are doing is old school / old style - Department.dID = Professor.dID.  Again, I'm not sure what you have been taught yet but it's generally accepted now to not have the table join clauses not in your where clause.  Instead the above query would look like:

```
SELECT d.name, p.pID, p.fname, p.lname, p.picpath, p.email 
FROM Department d
INNER JOIN Professor p on d.dID = p.dID
WHERE d.dID = ?
```

Of course, if you haven't been shown this yet then you might not want to use this syntax yet. :-)

**EDIT -** 
As I looked some more at your database model I am not sure why you have Professor comment.  This is a junction table but this kind of table is only needed when there is a many to many relationship.

The relationship of Professor to Comments is one to many.  A Professor may have many comments but a comment can only have one Professor.  If I understand this right then you don't need the Professor Comment table as the layout appears at the moment.

Comment: Good call on professor_comment, I will fix this then see if I can get it. Thanks Klabranche!

Comment: Good Luck and please feel free to ask more questions on SO @woopie. :-)